# Can i position:fixed a content inside TD for IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering if it is possible with Javascript or CSS in IE ?
I tried it with non IE browsers and they are working fine.
Built this little scnerio along with Valid DOCTYPE.Tested it with IE 9 and failed.

```
<div style="height:400px;width:400px;overflow:auto">
<table>
<tr>
<td>content</td>

<td>

<div style="position:fixed;height:100px;">
Long Content.............
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do. Strictly speaking there's nothing "wrong" with it, although it is unusual. However the element it will be fixed to may vary depending on the browser - it may be fixed to the window, or fixed to the closest parent with overflow. This discrepency may be the cause of your issues, and is why I recommended that `position:fixed` elements only be placed as direct children of the `body`.

Comment: Well! I am trying to show the vertical scrollbar of first DIV ,Where the second DIV Ends..And show the second DIV all the time when first DIV scroll.